# Comparação de tabelas

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Estou criando um sistema de bolão, onde o administrador cadastra os jogos e o placar, e o usuário tem a opção de chutar um placar, caso esse placar for igual ao cadastrado pelo administrador ele informa que o usuário acertou, caso contrario que errou.
Vou colocar o código em que o administrador cadastra a partida, o do usuário que aposta e também a imagem do banco de dados. Neste caso a chave primária é o `código da partida`

Tabela `tb_jogos` onde o administrador cadastra as partidas:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_jogos (
  casa varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  placarcasa int(1) NOT NULL,
  fora varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  placarfora int(1) NOT NULL,
  codigo int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
  PRIMARY KEY (codigo);
```

Código administrador para cadastrar partida:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!empty($_SESSION['email'])){

}else{
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Aréa Restrita.');
                window.location.href='/bolao/index.php';</script>";
}
$nome=$_SESSION['nome'];

$placarc = substr(mt_rand (0,5),0,1); //gera números de para time casa 0 a 5
$placarf = substr(mt_rand (0,5),0,1); //gera números de para time fora 0 a 5


$btnCadastrar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnCadastrar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnCadastrar){
    include_once ("../conn/conexao.php");
    $dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    $jogos = "INSERT INTO tb_jogos(casa, placarcasa, fora, placarfora, codigo)VALUES(
        '".$dados['casa']."',
        '".$dados['placarcasa']."',
        '".$dados['fora']."',
        '".$dados['placarfora']."',
        '".$dados['codigo']."'
        )";
        $mensagem="<script>alert('Codigo de partida ja cadastrado.');
                window.location='partidas.php';</script>";
    $resultado_jogos = mysqli_query($conexao, $jogos) or die ($mensagem);
    if($resultado_jogos):
        echo "<script>
                alert('Jogo cadastrado com sucesso.');
                window.location='index.php';
            </script>"; 
    else:
        echo "<script>
                alert('Ocorreu um erro ao cadastrar o jogo.');
                window.location='index.php';
            </script>";
    endif;
}

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">

    <title>Lance Web</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
    <!-- ALERTA: Respond.js nÃŖo funciona se vocÃĒ visualizar uma pÃĄgina file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->   

    <!-- Aqui começa o script para gerar um placar para o time casa -->
    <script>
        function myFunction(){
    document.getElementById("placar-c").value = <?php echo $placarc; ?>;
    }
    </script>

    <!-- Aqui começa o script para gerar um placar para o time fora -->
    <script>
        function myFunction2(){
    document.getElementById("placar-f").value = <?php echo $placarf; ?>;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<!--------------------------------------------------------- nav e o menu ------------------------------------------------------------------->   
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Aqui e como ira aparece em um telefone -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <!-- Aqui no span, sÃŖo os 3 pontos ao abrir em um telefone -->
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Voltar</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Aqui se edita a parte do saldo -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="partidas.php">Cadastrar Partidas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
            <li class=""><a href="editarpartidas.php">Editar Partidas<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>

            <!-- Aqui se edita a parte do sair -->  
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li><a href="sair.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></a></li>
             </ul>

    </div><!-- fim da div collapse, ela faz com que abra um menu ao aumentar o site -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!------------------------------------------------- Aqui começa o formulario de cadastrar os placares ------------------------------------->    
    <form class="form-group" action="" method="post">
        <div class="container" align="center" >
            <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"><br>
                <label id="font">Time Casa</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="casa" required>
                         <option selected></option>
                         <option value="Atletico-go">Atlético-GO</option>
                         <option value="Atletico-mg">Atlético-MG</option>
                         <option value="Atletico-pr">Atlético-PR</option>
                         <option value="Avai">Avaí</option>
                         <option value="Bahia">Bahia</option>
                         <option value="Botafogo">Botafogo</option>
                         <option value="Corinthians">Corinthians</option>
                         <option value="Coritiba">Coritiba</option>
                         <option value="Cruzeiro">Cruzeiro</option>
                         <option value="Chapecoense">Chapecoense</option>
                    </select><br>

                <label id="font">Placar time Casa</label>   
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-3">
                            <input id="placar-c" class="form-control" type="text" name="placarcasa" maxlength="1" value="" style="text-align: center;" required /></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input class="btn btn-success submit-botao" type="submit" value="Gerar" onclick="myFunction()">
                        </div>
                    </div><hr><br><!-- Fim div row placar casa-->

                <label id="font">Time Fora</label>
                    <select class="form-control" name="fora" required>
                        <option selected></option>
                        <option value="Flamengo">Flamengo</option>
                        <option value="Fluminense">Fluminense</option>
                        <option value="Gremio">Grêmio</option>
                        <option value="Palmeiras">Palmeiras</option>
                        <option value="Ponte preta">Ponte Preta</option>
                        <option value="Santos">Santos</option>
                        <option value="Sao paulo">São Paulo</option>
                        <option value="Sport">Sport</option>
                        <option value="Vasco">Vasco</option>
                        <option value="Vitoria">Vitória</option>
                </select><br>

                <label id="font">Placar time fora</label>   
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3 col-xs-3">
                            <input id="placar-f" class="form-control" type="text" name="placarfora" maxlength="1" value="" style="text-align: center;" required /></div>
                        <div class="col-xs-4">
                            <input class="btn btn-success submit-botao" type="submit" value="Gerar" onclick="myFunction2()">
                        </div>
                    </div><hr><!-- Fim div row placar fora-->

                    <label id="font">Codigo da partida</label>  
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 col-xs-3">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="codigo" maxlength="5" style="text-align: center;" required></div>
                    </div><hr><br><!-- Fim div row placar casa-->

                    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1"> 
                        <a href="index.php"><input class="btn btn-danger btn-lg" type="button" value="Cancelar"></a>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-md-5 col-md-offset-1">
                        <input class="btn btn-info btn-lg submit-botao" type="submit" value="Cadastrar" name="btnCadastrar">
                    </div>

            </div><!-- Fim div mover-->

        </div><!-- Fim div container -->

    </form><!-- Fim formulario-->

    </div><!-- Fim Div row-->

    </div><!-- Fim Div container-->

<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Tabela tb_aposta onde o usuário faz as apostas:

```
CREATE TABLE tb_aposta (
  apostacasa int(1) NOT NULL,
  apostafora int(1) NOT NULL,
  valor int(10) NOT NULL,
  data varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  usuario varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  codigopartida int(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (codigopartida);
```

Código do usuário onde ele realiza a aposta:

```
<?php
session_start();
include_once("../conn/conexao.php");
if(!empty($_SESSION['email'])){

}else{
    echo"<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>alert('Aréa Restrita.');
                window.location.href='/bolao/index.php';</script>";
}
$nome=$_SESSION['nome'];
$email=$_SESSION['email'];
$saldo="SELECT * FROM tb_usuario WHERE email= '$email'";
$exe= mysqli_query($conexao, $saldo);
$linha = mysqli_fetch_array($exe);

$btnApostar = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'btnApostar', FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
if($btnApostar){
    include_once ("../conn/conexao.php");
    $dados = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_DEFAULT);

    $aposta = "INSERT INTO tb_aposta(apostacasa, apostafora, valor, data, usuario, codigopartida)VALUES(
        '".$dados['apostacasa']."',
        '".$dados['apostafora']."',
        '".$dados['valor']."',
        '".$dados['data']."',
        '".$_SESSION['nome']."',
        '".$dados['codigopartida']."'
        )";
    $r_aposta = mysqli_query($conexao, $aposta) or die (mysqli_error($conexao));
    if($r_aposta):
        echo "<script>
                alert('Apostado com sucesso.');
                window.location='index.php';
            </script>"; 
    else:
        echo "<script>
                alert('Ocorreu um erro ao apostar no jogo.');
                window.location='index.php';
            </script>";
    endif;
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css'/>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- As 3 meta tags acima *devem* vir em primeiro lugar dentro do `head`; qualquer outro conteúdo deve vir *após* essas tags -->
    <title>Lance Web</title>
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim e Respond.js para suporte no IE8 de elementos HTML5 e media queries -->
    <!-- ALERTA: Respond.js não funciona se você visualizar uma página file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>
<!-- nav e o menu -->   
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <!-- Aqui e como ira aparece em um telefone -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <!-- Aqui no span, são os 3 pontos ao abrir em um telefone -->
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">Voltar</a>
    </div>

    <!-- Aqui se edita a parte do saldo -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a>Saldo&nbsp; R$<?php echo $linha['saldo']; ?><span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="apostar.php">Apostar<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="">Histórico<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="ranking.php">Ranking<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class=""><a href="loja/loja.php">Loja<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        </ul>
            <!-- Aqui se edita a parte do sair -->  
             <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                 <li><a href="sair.php"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></i></a></li>
             </ul>

    </div><!-- fim da div collapse, ela faz com que abra um menu ao aumentar o site -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>

<!------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------>

        <?php
                include("../conn/conexao.php");
                //ORDER BY serve para organizar os dados de acordo com o que voce quiser
                $buscar="SELECT * FROM tb_jogos ORDER BY codigo DESC";
                $exe= mysqli_query($conexao, $buscar) or die ("OCORREU UM ERRO AO MOSTRAR OS DADOS");
                //começo da tabela
                echo "<br><br><div class='container'>
                        <table class='table table-inverse'>
                          <thead>
                            <tr bgcolor='#222222' align='center'>
                              <th><font color='white'>Codigo Partida</font></th>
                              <th><font color='white'>Time Casa</font></th>
                              <th><font color='white'>Placar</font></th>
                              <th><font color='white'>Time Fora</font></th>
                              <th><font color='white'>Placar</font></th>
                              <th><font color='white'>Lance</font></th>
                              <th><font color='white'></font></th>
                            </tr>
                         </thead>
                      </div>";


                while($linha = mysqli_fetch_array($exe)){
                    echo "<form class='form-group' action='' method='post'>
                          <tbody>
                            <tr bgcolor='#222222'>
                              <td><font color='white'><input type='int' class='form-control' name='codigopartida' maxlength='1' value=".$linha['codigo']." style='text-align: center;' readonly='readonly'></font></td>
                              <td><font color='white'>".$linha['casa']."</font></td>
                              <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='apostacasa' maxlength='1' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
                              <td><font color='white'>".$linha['fora']."</font></td>
                              <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='apostafora' maxlength='1' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
                              <td><input type='int' class='form-control' name='valor' maxlength='5' value='' style='text-align: center;'></td>
                              <td><input class='btn btn-success submit-botao' type='submit' value='Apostar' name='btnApostar'></td>
                            </tr>
                          </tbody>
                          </form>";

                }
        ?>


<script src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'></script>
<script src='//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer Então na pagina do usuário apostar eu preciso que logo depois que ele colocar os placares da partida seja feita um comparação com os placares que o administrador cadastrou, se for igual ele acerta se for errado ele erra...

Comment: Existe duas tabelas uma (tb_jogos) para guarda o resultado que o administrador deu e outra tabela (tb_apostas) para guarda o resultado em que o usuário deu, então eu não aprendi ajax ainda, mais se quiser dar um exemplo aceito sim, mais minha grande dúvida é na comparação das tabelas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A primeira coisa que você precisa ter em mente é a ligação(referencia) entre as duas tabelas para saber qual aposta faz referencia a qual partida, então teremos:

Tabela `tb_jogos` onde o administrador cadastra as partidas:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_jogos` (
  `id_jogo` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `casa` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `placarcasa` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `fora` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `placarfora` int(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Tabela `tb_aposta` onde o usuário faz as apostas:

```
   CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tb_aposta` (
  `id_aposta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_jogo` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `apostacasa` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `apostafora` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `valor` float NOT NULL,
  `data` date NOT NULL,
  `usuario` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Note que na segunda tabela foi adicionado um campo de id do jogo, para saber sobre qual jogo foi feita a aposta.

Achei que ficaram muitos códigos para postar aqui, então subi para um repositório no `Github`.

> [Repositório](https://github.com/darleizillmer/lance)
>
> https://github.com/darleizillmer/lance